FAR 91.411 and 91.413 pitot/static and transponder tests when overseas
I own an N-registered aircraft and am overseas with it. The aircraft requires compliance with FAR 91.411 and FAR 91.413. In looking at the FAA database for repair stations, I don't see a station authorized to perform these tests in this country. I'm a bit stumped, how can I comply with these regulations?

In what country?

Do the US regulations apply when flying in foreign airspace?

@mins Most of them do, yes, under 14 CFR § 91.703, unless preempted by local or ICAO regulations.

To the points above: they do for the aircraft. There are reciprocal arrangements. My question is how to get the required FAA paperwork to comply with them?

You don't need to find a full FAA-certified repair station. Anyone with a US airframe mechanic rating and access to the proper equipment with current calibrations can do that for you. Pitot-static and transponder test equipment is a fairly common thing to find, especially if you are US certified and offering your services overseas.
AC-43-6D states...

MAINTENANCE. Any appropriately rated person (as specified in § 43.3) may perform maintenance or preventive maintenance on an aircraft altitude reporting and transponder system. This work may include the removal of and/or replacement with an identical system component. An appropriately rated person can approve the aircraft for return to service only after the performance of a suitable functional check of the entire system (as installed in the aircraft) to determine that the system, as well as the component, will perform its intended functions.


Yes. In the end that’s what I found out.
